# How to use embedded resource in ASP.Net?

Tags: .net, embedded-resource

I'm practicing to use embedded resource in ASP.Net. I wrote a javascript file, put it into a C# class library and change It's Build Action Property to Embedded Resource. In my web project, I added reference to the that class library. I want to use that javascript file in my web pages but i don't know how? please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was resolved.
Anybody can accomplish as following steps:
- Add a class library to your solution
- Add the resource files which you want to embed
- Register your resource in AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("A.B.C", "D")]
```

with: 
A is your class library name
B is the folder's name which contain your resource file
C is the resource files'name
D is the content type of your resource ("text/javascript" or another)

- In the code behind file of the asp.net page you include the resource:

string scriptLocation = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(typeof(the empty class' name which added before), "A.B.C");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("A.B.C", scriptLocation);

- test what you have done